# How to compute $(1 − i \sqrt{3})^3\cdot(1 + i)^2$ using the trigonometric form of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to compute it using the trigonometric form of complex numbers: $$(1 − i \sqrt{3})^3\cdot(1 + i)^2$$

I computed it using the standard method: $-16i$

Comment: The first step would be converting both numbers to their trigonomic form

Comment: @Dasherman If I plot $z_1=-8$ and $z_2=2i$ I get that in both cases $\theta =0$. What to do?

Comment: I suggest you start with $z_1=1-\sqrt{3}i$ and $z_2=1+i$ and write them in their trig form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $1 - i\sqrt{3}= z_ 1 = 2(\cos \frac{5\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{5\pi }{3})$ and $1 +  i =z_2 = \sqrt{2}(\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + i\sin \frac{\pi}{4})$

And use [Moivre's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula).

Comment: I get $-2$ for $z_1$...

Comment: Did you compute $z_1^3 = 2^3(\cos \frac{15\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{15\pi}{3})$? It should be $-8$.

Comment: And $z_2 ^2 = 2i$.

Comment: Yes! I forgot about $2^3$... Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Given $z=x+iy$ you can convert this to:$$z=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))=re^{i\theta}$$where:$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{y}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{-1\pm i\sqrt3}2$ are among the three cube roots of unity, meaning $\dfrac{1\pm i\sqrt3}2$ are among the three cube roots of $-1$. Also, $\pm\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$ are the two square roots of *i*.